# JQuery notifications stack to slide out one by one

Tags: jquery, notifications

I want to create notifications so that when something is saved on page or some error happens a notification appears saying the results.

HTML and JQuery both work fine they stack up so if 3 notifications happen at the same time all 3 slide in but when it comes fading them out within 5 seconds only the top one slides out.

Here is the JQuery code:

```
 var notificationsQueue = [];

 function createNotification(text) {
   $obj = $('<div>' + 
            '<div class="notification animated">' + 
                '<div class="notification-left-container">' + 
                    '<div class="notification-icon"></div>' + 
                '</div>' + 
                '<div class="notification-right-container">' + 
                    '<div class="notification-right-inner-container">'+text+'</div>' + 
                '</div>' + 
                '<div class="notification-clear-both"></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
        '</div>').prependTo('#notifications_list div.notifications-pusher');

   $obj.show('slide', {
     direction: 'left'
   }, 500);

   notificationsQueue.push($obj);
 }
```

now above code displays notifications on top of each other. When it comes to slide them out
I use the following code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (notificationsQueue.length) {
        $obj = notificationsQueue.pop();


        setTimeout(function() {
            $obj.hide('slide', {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 500);
        }, 3000);

    }
}, 500);
```

so every **half** a second it checks if notifications queue is empty if not then pop the last one and slide out in 3 seconds. Above code only slides out the top div and not the rest of them. Rest of them stay on page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code snippet how $obj is defined, but seems it is a global variable. and before first 'hide' is called, the value of $obj is rewritten by several calls of anonymous function from setInterval.

so change $obj to be a [local var](http://jsfiddle.net/bmanvelyan/nBWxx/#base), then each time anonymous function in setTimeout will get it own reference to $obj. see [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (notificationsQueue.length) {
        var $obj = notificationsQueue.pop();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $obj.hide('slide', {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 500);
        }, 3000);
    }
}, 500);
```